# VBA Getting column name based off if value is in that column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code in which the VBA searches the table range and returns to column name based off if that cell value is in the column.
[image]
For instance if the value entered is "J-box" it returns the column name "3".

I know how to do this with index match in the excel formula's but I am trying to do it such that if my tech's select the location name, it pulls the correlated location number to a textbox in a userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by doing this

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set iSheet = Worksheets("Locations")
iSheet.Range("P1").Interior.Color = RGB(100, 200, 1)
Match1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSheet.Range("P1"), iSheet.Range("A1:A23"), 0)
Match2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSheet.Range("P2"), iSheet.Range("B" & Match1 & ":N" & Match1), 0)

iSheet.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(iSheet.Range("B1:N1"), _
Match2)


End Sub
```